# i18n-webpack-plugin doesn't work with .tpl files

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, internationalization, webpack, lodash

My problem is:

I write an SPA on Backbone with lodash templates (webpack use it from 'templates' folder). And I try to use i18n-webpack-plugin. 
I have buttons in my lodash templates, and I want to translate the text on it. But I don't know how, because <%= __("Permissions") { %> doesn't work here (only in .tpl files, in .js it works).

My webpack.config.js is:

```
var webpack = require('webpack'),
    I18nPlugin = require("i18n-webpack-plugin"),

    languages = {
        "en": null,
        "de": require("./resources/lang/de/interface.json"),
        "es": require("./resources/lang/es/interface.json")
    };

module.exports = Object.keys(languages).map(function(language) {
    return {
        name: language,
        entry: {
            acl: "./resources/views/js/acl/init"
        },
        output: {
            path: __dirname + "/public/profile/static/js/dist/",
            filename: language + ".[name].js"
        },
        resolve: {
            alias: {
                "backbone": __dirname + "/resources/views/js/lib/backbone/backbone",
                "jquery": __dirname + "/resources/views/js/lib/jquery/dist/jquery",
                "lodash": __dirname + "/resources/views/js/lib/lodash/lodash",
                "underscore": __dirname + "/resources/views/js/lib/lodash/lodash",
                "models": __dirname + "/resources/views/js/acl/models/",
                "collections": __dirname + "/resources/views/js/acl/collections/",
                "views": __dirname + "/resources/views/js/acl/views/",
                "routers": __dirname + "/resources/views/js/acl/routers/",

                "templates": __dirname + "/resources/views/templates/",
            }
        },
        devtool: "source-map",
        module: {
            loaders: [{
                test: /\.tpl$/,
                loader: "text",
        }]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
        new I18nPlugin(
            languages[language]
        ),
    ],
   }
});
```

This is my "templates": __dirname + "/resources/views/templates/" example:

```
<h1 class="s-h4"><%= __("Permissions") { %></h1>
```

This is my ./resources/lang/es/interface.json

```
{
    "Permissions": "Permisos"
}
```

After webpack work in the result file (es.acl.js) I see <%= __("Permissions") { %>, but I want to see Permisos

Comment: Can you provide a more complete example in jsfiddle.com, something basic that shows the problem. Thanks